# Why is failed job not logged in SQL Server Agent Error Log?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, jobs, logs, error-log

I have a failed job which is logged in SQL Server Logs but not logged in SQL Server Agent Error Logs. The job is executed as user: `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT`. `Limit size of job history` and `Remove agent history` boxes are unchecked in properties of SQL Server Agent. Here are the results of SQL Server Logs:

[image]

When it comes to SQL Server Agent Error Logs, it does not contain any information about this failure. I thought that if a job fails then it should be necessarily logged into SQL Server Agent Error Logs. Why this happens?

Comment: Is the error contained in the Job Step history for the failed execution?

Comment: Yes. I can see it in job step history